# Stream SQL FOR XML into response and zip

Tags: asp.net, xml, zip, gzip, xmlwriter

I have a SQL FOR XML query which I am streaming straight into the response via a .net XmlWriter.

Is it possible to GZIP this directly into the response?

We have some massive XML files (over 2 million items with multiple attributes - the raw files are several GB once created) which we are distributing to our customers. Up until now we have been unable to compress without first creating a file or writing to memory. However, both of these have massive performance bottlenecks in terms of IO and memory capacity.

If anyone can provide some advice its greatly appreciated. I'm happy to provide any additional info that can help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do this. Have a look at ionic.zip as an example, there are other .NET components that let you create a ZIP on the fly and stream it back to the browser in the response.

Comment: Thanks I have had a look at ionic. So this allows you to wrap a zip stream around the xmlwriter stream without writing the whole response to memory first?

Comment: Ahh no I don't think it does. Or at least the version I used (I looked at some code I wrote 3 years) didn't, not sure if it's changed since then.